# Try/Catch in every method of every class?

Tags: c#, exception

When we wrap a bunch of statements in a try/catch and one of these issues an exception, within the catch we have no way of knowing which of the statements caused the exception (the ex.stacktrace shows our current method (doit), its caller, its caller's caller, etc. but neither do1 or do2):

```
function doit() {
   try {
     do1();
     do2();
     [...]
   }
   catch (Exception ex) {
     // what failed?
   }
}
```

generally I've taken to wrapping all statements and rethrowing, sort of like:

```
private void do1() {
  try {
     // do whatever
  } catch(Exception e) {
     // write to my error log
     throw new Exception("do1: " + e.Message, e.InnerException);
  }
}
```

which leaves a trail of breadcrumbs in my log and makes the chain available for the upstream.  The problem, of course, is that I have to wrap *every* method I write with this kind of code.

something tells me I'm being dumb about it.  what is the right approach?

Comment: You will get the line number of the exception in the stack trace as long as the ".pdb" file is available. Alternatively, set some form of indicator when you are at logical points in the method, and if the method gets an exception write this to the log as well. Don't put try-catch all over the place.

Comment: I don't understand the motivation for this. In the first example, the stacktrace would have `do1()` on top, yes?

Comment: This is a terrible idea that pretty much every developer tries at some point.

Comment: The exception's stack trace will show where the exception originated from (method and possibly line number), regardless of where you caught it.

Comment: You're probably doing `throw ex;` at every level. Stop that. And stop catching it at every level. Catch it where you can handle it in whatever appropriate fashion, be it logging or whatever. Nowhere else.

Comment: Don't throw a new Exception. Do your logging and then rethrow the same exception `e`.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill: no, that's precisely the problem.  the top of the stack would contain the function that contains the try/catch, so I don't know whether do1() or do2() issued the exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are really sold on doing this (others have stated why this is bad already), use an Aspect Oriented Programming approach. This will make your life significantly easier and reduce the amount of code you end up writing and maintaining.

Take a look at [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/), it gives you a framework that allows you to decorate methods, classes, or namespaces with attributes that will generate this boilerplate error handling for you.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  it's something I've been curious about for a bit so I'll need to look into it

Answer (score 9):

Ok, this is hard to get right because exception handling is a really really touchy subject and in the past people have fought religious wars over how to do this right.

First off: neither use an empty catch (`try { ... } catch { ... }`), nor `catch(Exception ex)`.
The sole purpose of Exception-derived classes is to give you rich information about the kind of exception which occured so you can do something meaningful in your exception handler (if a thread crashed restart it, if a db connection failed non-permanently try again, then fail, etc).

People tend to use a catch-all handler for the outermost part of their code to log uncaught exceptions and this is kind of OK, but in any case you should either prompt the user or rethrow the exception (using `throw`, not `throw ex` - there is a ton of discussion about this as well).

Basically you do not programmatically care about where the Exception occured **at all**.
You can either handle it or you can't. If you can't handle it then you don't catch it.

**Addendum**: The most important reason for this "if you can do something about it, do so, otherwise dont you dare touch that exception" philosophy is that silently caught exceptions (whether logged or not) can lead to really hard-to-find bugs. Just pushing them out to a logfile might not be enough because in a live system you may not get the fully annotated stack trace (with line numbers and everything).

**Addendum 2**: Take for instance a textbox which expects an integer input. If the user supplies a string you cannot meaningfully process the input, maybe a conversion exception gets thrown, you catch that specific exception and reset the textbox to its old value and maybe inform the user about the erroneous input. Alternatively your program might either just die with an exception (bad design, you could recover from that exception) or silently go on showing the erroneous input, but still using the old value (bad design, the program is misleading).

Comment: I would disagree on the Exception ex.  There are some points in a system where you want any exception caught so it doesn't travel any further up the stack.  An example of this would be in your application start up class.  Catch the unhandled exception, log it, display a message to your user, then handle gracefully instead of crashing the app.

Comment: I do agree on don't touch the exception if you aren't going to handle it for the most part.  The only way I would say otherwise is if you are exposing API's and you want "API Internal" logging but still want the exception thrown back to the consumer.  +1 for your answer.

Comment: You are right, catching on Exception can be used as a desperate last resort for the program to gracefully die or restart (of course if the exception was OutOfMemory and you allocate any mem in your exception handler it bubbles out anyways :)

Answer (score 3):

@Branko nailed it in the comments: the exception's stack trace shows the point where the exception was thrown, not where it was caught.

+1 for @ChaosPandion's comment: this is a very, very, very bad idea.

Comment: you're right.  I can't figure out what I was thinking when I wrote this.  I'll need to revisit.

Comment: In re-reading my original posting I understand again my issue and that it was expressed correctly.  the issue is that the stack trace does not indicate whether do1() or do2() issued the exception and that is what I need to know at the point I catch it.  So if you look, at the top of the stack trace is the method containing the try/catch, not the method that issued the exception.  I'm thus reopening this question.  thanks.

Comment: If you're not re-throwing the exception, the original stack trace should start with the actual exception throw location, and include the entire path back.  This should either include do1() or do2() ... unless the exception is in harvesting the parameters to call them.  Imagine `do1(somelist.Count)` where `somelist` was null.

Comment: placing a debugger breakpoint within my catch shows a stack trace beginning with the function that contains the try/catch.  this is my issue, that I can't tell whether do1() or do2() caused the exception.  I'm uncertain what you mean by "harvesting the parameters to call them", but if we defined void do1() { throw ... } I would want to see do1() (and probably the line within it) in the stack trace

Comment: robrich, (for some reason the at-sign-name doesn't seem to work) your comment (and Anthony Pegram's above) prompted me to look into the question of throw/rethrow.  I found this: http://goo.gl/0l0OK which may be what's harming me.  I need to review the code to see whether there are "new" throws that are discarding my stack...

Answer (score 2):

`try` and `catch` seem to me to be probably the single worst designed modern programming mechanism. We no longer have the ability to handle errors as we go; we *must* fail the entire procedure if a single exception occurs, unless we do something horrifying like try every statement individually. There is no longer the option of recovering, only failing as gracefully as possible.

The best pattern for this I have found so far is to wrap every user event in a `try`/`catch` (using a method, not an explicit try every time). Ex:

```
public static class Defines
{
   public static bool TryAction(Action pAction)
   {
      try { pAction(); return true; }
      catch(Exception exception) { PostException(exception); return false; }
   }
}

...

private void DoSomething(int pValue)
{
   ...
}

private void MyControl_MyEvent(object pSender, MyEventArgs pEventArgs)
{
   Defines.TryAction(() => DoSomething(pEventArgs.Data));
}
```

Beyond that, just try to write exception-less code. Only use explicit `try`s when you are very likely to get an exception and want to do a little more than just fail gracefully.